# Using MapThread with pure function and variable number of elements

Tags: pure-function, mapthread

I have a variable size array of lists and would like to set up a MapThread of the lists with a variable pure function $\{\#1,\#2,...,\#n\}\&$ with $n$ being the number of rows in the array and am unable to code this as if I try constructs like

```
function = Table[
  "#" <> ToString[n],
  {n, 1, 5}]

(* {"#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5"} *)
```

or:

```
function = Table[
  ToString[#] <> ToString[n],
  {n, 1, 5}]

(*  {"#11", "#12", "#13", "#14", "#15"} *)
```

and then MapThread the function like:

```
MapThread[
 function &, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2,3}}]
```

I receive the error

> incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 4} and {2, 5} of 
> MapThread[function&,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{1,2.3}}]; 
> dimensions are 3 and 2

Can someone help me with this or perhaps refer a link that would demonstrate this type of construct?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding a bounty suggest that none of the answers so far were sufficient. But they all seem to solve the problem as presented. Is there more information you can provide to indicate why these answers don't suffice?

Comment: They are all sufficient.  I just want to reward an existing answer as per the bounty description.  Also trivial looking, it was a bottleneck in my work and the solutions helped my progress and I appreciate the expertise given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious about why you think you need to specify all the slots. `MapThread` works just fine like this:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}};

MapThread[g, list]
(* {g[1, 4, 1, 4, 1], g[2, 5, 2, 5, 2], g[3, 6, 3, 6, 3]} *)
```

And in your specific example, we can just swap `g` for `List`:

```
MapThread[List, list]
(* {{1, 4, 1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3, 6, 3}} *)
```

And if you do need slots for some reason, you don't need to specify all of them. You can just use `SlotSequence`:

```
MapThread[h[##] &, list]
(* {h[1, 4, 1, 4, 1], h[2, 5, 2, 5, 2], h[3, 6, 3, 6, 3]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  In an earlier comment which I deleted,  I thought List wouldn't work but was only due to my lack of understanding.  The construct MapThread[List,myList] is really concise and reduces the amount of code..

Answer (score 4):

No need to make list of each slot, use `##` which is sequence of all slots/arguments.

```
MapThread[{##} &, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 
   3}}]
```

---

```
{{1, 4, 1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3, 6, 3}}
```

The same can be achieved by:

```
Transpose@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}};

fun = Table[Slot @ n, {n, 5}];

MapThread[Evaluate @ fun &, list]
```

{{1, 4, 1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3, 6, 3}}

The `Evaluate` is needed because `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Another way using `Thread` and `MapApply`:

```
Thread[list]

(*{{1, 4, 1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 3, 6, 3}}*)

g @@@ Thread[list]

(*{g[1, 4, 1, 4, 1], g[2, 5, 2, 5, 2], g[3, 6, 3, 6, 3]}*)
```